# Dot product of a vector in SciPy/NumPy (getting ValueError: objects are not aligned)

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I just started learning SciPy and am struggling with the most basic features.

Consider the following standard vector:

```
In [6]: W=array([[1],[2]])

In [7]: print W
[[1]
 [2]]
```

If I understand it correctly, this should be the SciPy representation of a standard 2x1 mathematical vector, like this:

```
(1)    
(2)
```

The dot product of this vector should simply be `1*1+2*2=5`. However, this does not work in SciPy:

```
In [16]: dot(W, W)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/ingo/<ipython-input-16-961b62a82495> in <module>()
----> 1 dot(W, W)

ValueError: objects are not aligned
```

Note that the following works. This should be a vector of the form `(1 2)` if I am not mistaken.

```
In [9]: V=array([1,2])

In [10]: print V
[1 2]

In [11]: dot(V, V)
Out[11]: 5
```

What is my misconception? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can forget about "rows" and "columns" when using *arrays*. Notice that you need it when using *matrices* though.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The key here is that numpy/scipy honours the shape of arrays when computing dot products. Looking at your first example, `W` is a 2x1 array:

```
In [7]: W=array([[1],[2]])

In [8]: print W.shape
------> print(W.shape)
(2, 1)
```

it is, therefore, necessary to use the transpose operator to compute the dot (inner) product of W with itself:

```
In [9]: print dot(W.T,W)
------> print(dot(W.T,W))
[[5]]

In [10]: print np.asscalar(dot(W.T,W))
-------> print(np.asscalar(dot(W.T,W)))
5
```

Answer (score 12):

You should use `vdot`: "Return the dot product of two vectors." This function flattens the input arguments and gives the results you expect. For your example:

```
>>> W = np.array([[1], [2]])
>>> np.vdot(W, W)
5
>>>
```

Answer (score 4):

In your first case numpy is generating the vector as a two-dimensional array, basically a 2-by-1 matrix.  In that case the dot product cannot be taken because and m-by-n matrix can be dotted only with an n-by-k matrix.  The solution is to use:

```
dot(W.T,W)
```

This is the same as how x.x is sometimes written x^T x.

In the second case, for convenience numpy is generating a one-dimensional array instead of a matrix, so the dot product has a simple definition.  If you were to generate a 1-by-2 matrix using

```
W = np.array([[1,2]])
```

then you would get the same behaviour as in the first case.

Answer (score 3):

You're mistaken about the shape of the array you pass in:

```
>>> W = np.array([[1], [2]])
>>> W.shape
(2, 1)
>>> W = np.array([1, 2])
>>> W.shape
(2,)
```

As you've observed, using `np.dot` on the second definition of `W` works as expected. To dot a 2-d matrix with itself, when it isn't square, you must transpose:

```
>>> W = np.array([[1], [2]])
>>> np.dot(W, W.transpose())
array([[1, 2],
       [2, 4]])
```

A shortcut for `transpose` is `W.T`

Note that the shape of the output differs depending on whether you start with the transposition or the original, as one would expect:

```
>>> np.dot(W.T, W)
array([[5]])
>>> np.dot(W.T, W).shape
(1, 1)
```

See the [numpy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) docs for more.

Answer (score 0):

That's an array of two arrays, not an array of two values.  The first one could be thought of as a matrix: two rows with one column each.

The second one is correct; it gives you right correct dot product as well.  Believe your eyes; use the second one.

Comment: Ok, so is `V=array([1,2])` a vector with two rows and one column, or one column and two rows?

Comment: @Ingo, it's a vector with one row and no columns. It's a 1-d vector. `numpy` distinguishes between arrays and matrices of shape `(2,)` and shape `(2, 1)` or shape `(1, 2)`.

Comment: It's a row vector: 1 row, two columns.  OR a column vector: 2 rows, 1 column.  Depends on how it's used.  that's what a mathematician would say

Answer (score 0):

In the first example, W is a 2 dimensionnal array, whereas in the last one (the one which works), you have just 1 dim.

Yon can be sure the 2nd way is the right way to do this.